# Run Python Script From Script Directory/Current Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Introduction]

Hi! I'm working on a python script to automate installation of UWP-Apps, it's been a long time i'm not touching Python; until this day. The script uses Depedencies inside the script directory, i've looking up on my older scripts and found this specific code.

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

[Problematic]

However, using the above code doesn't work on my current script but it's working fine on older scripts. When using above, it shows:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''
```

Already looking up on Internet about this topic; but most of them was talking about running the script from outer/different directory that leads me to dead end.

Any helps is appreciated :)

Comment: No, it didnt require such. In fact, its working as like: cd /d "%~dp0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
os.chdir(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
```

You can use `dirname(abspath(__file__)))` to get the parent directory of the python script and `os.chdir` into it to make the script run in the directory where it is located.

Comment: This is probably the closest answer from what i needed, both answer is really usefull. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### The easiest answer is probably to change your working directory, then call the `.py` file from where it is:

```
cd path/to/python/file && python ../.py
```

---

#### Of course you might find it even easier to write a script that does it all for you, like so:

Save this as `runPython.sh` in the directory where you're running the python script from, is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd path/to/python/file
python ../script.py
```

Make it executable (for yourself):

```
chmod +x ./runPython.sh
```

Then you can simply enter your directory and run it:

```
./runPython.sh
```

---

#### If you want to only make changes to the python script:

```
mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the folder where you're running the file
mydir_tmp = "path/to/python/file" # get the path
mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir_tmp) # change the current working directory
mydir = os.getcwd()
```

The reason you got an error was because `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the file itself, instead you can pass the directory as a string and use `sys.argv[1]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works but need to use work-around, usefull if im placing the depedencies on the temp folder.